# How to test ngOnDestroy on service in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have non-singleton service that it supposed to change state of other service on creation, but revert it when service is destroyed

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(private anotherService: AnotherService
  ) {
    anotherService.mute(true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.anotherService.mute(false);
  }
```

How to verify that that `ngOnDestroy` is indeed called using TestBed? Currently I calling `ngOnDestroy` directly to assert its implementation, but what if I want to assert that it is correctly integrated with angular component (service here) lifecycle?

What I do now:

```
      it('mutes on creation and unmutes on destruction', () => {
        expect(anotherService.mute).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
//        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment() // breaks tests
//        TestBed.resetTestingModule() // not doing what I want
        service.ngOnDestroy(); // how to use TestBed to invoke component lifecycle?
        expect(anotherService.mute).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
      });
```

what I have tried but does not work